# Python code is working in PyCharm not Visual Code Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, while-loop, try-catch

I'm following a beginner's Python course and the code the instructor has used works in PyCharm but not Visual Studio Code. I am learning how to use the try-catch within a while loop.

I have checked the Python version in Visual Studio Code and it is the same as in PyCharm (3.9).

I am not sure what is causing the error in Visual Studio Code. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?

The code is:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("What is x? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("x is not an integer")
    else:
        break

print(f"x is {x}")
```

The code works as expected in PyCharm, but when I run it in Visual Studio Code, I get the following output:

```
What is x? print(f"x is {x}")
x is not an integer
What is x? 50
```

not as it should be which is:

```
What is x? cat
x is not an integer
What is x? 45
x is 45
```

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? Good job laying out the code and responses. The visual studio run output seems ok. Did you enter `print(f"x is {x}"` in response to the prompt or did that just appear?

Answer (score 0):

As i see vscode doesn't execute the code outside of your loop, right? run the code in command line:

`python your_file.py`

if the output is same as PyCharm there might be something wrong with the configuration of your vscode, or maybe some extension causing errors

Answer (score 0):

Your code work perfectly.

You're receiving ValueError because the string input is being converted to int. what'll happen if the user enter a letter or a character?

A ValueError is a type of exception that is raised when a function or operation receives an argument with the correct data type but an inappropriate value. It occurs when the input value is not within the expected range or doesn't fit the constraints defined by the function or operation.

If you try to convert a string to an integer using the int() function, and the string does not represent a valid integer, a ValueError will be raised.

for example:

`# Trying to convert a non-integer string (letters, characters) to an integer   x = int(input("What is x? ")) # user input: & or A etc...`

This will result in a ValueError

Answer (score 0):

Your code work in vscode on my machine. do you have the correct vscode python extension? make sure the python extension you have installed is from Microsoft

How to check:

1. open vscode
2. click extension
3. search python
4. look for the one with the Microsoft checkmark

you could also try the following code:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("What is x? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("x is not an integer")
    else:
        print(f"x is {x}")
        break;
```

the sudo code for the above read:

```
while True:
    try:
       # Do something that might cause an exception
    except:
       # Do this if there was an exception. 
       # In your case: user input is not an integer value
    else: 
       # do this if there was no exceptions
       # exit the loop
```

Good luck.

Feel free to reach out on GitHub or discord. I will be more than happen to provide help during my free time.